# How to change the default gateway of a Mac OSX machine

Tags: macos, network

I am familiar with the `route add default gw` command in Linux to add a default gateway, but this doesn't work on Mac OS. I can't find any appropriate example in the route manual. Can anyone help me find the command.

Comment: Or how to make the IP address of one interface the default gateway?

Answer (score 29):

```bash
sudo route delete default
sudo route add default 192.168.0.1
```

or

```bash
sudo route change default -interface $INTF
sudo route change 192.168.0.0/16 -interface $INTF
```

Comment: is it possible to bind a route to a network environment ?

Comment: Can this also be reset to default afterwards?

Comment: @lony: If the default gateway is given by your DHCP server, it will get back to that on restart or when the network interface goes down and comes up again or when you change the Wifi access point.

Answer (score 15):

Go to System Preference >> Network, and you can "Set Service Order" of the network interfaces and effectively change the default route order in the routing table.

[image: change default route ordering]

Comment: Man, you are the best! That exactly I need :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are intent on using `route` the [man page for route](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/route.8.html) will show you it's the same as most BSD route commands. You may need `ip6config` [(and man page)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ip6config.8.html) as well if you care about IPv6 routing.

The "mac" way is to set it from the System Preference pane under network and is preferred over using unix commands since it honors location changes and other events such as a reboot.

[image: manual TCP/IP configuration]

Comment: But in that very screenshot, you will get an error message if you press "OK" since this method also require you to set a manual IPv4 Address, which might not be desirable.

Comment: @Fuzzy76 Yes - if you manually set an unworkable network, your network will not work. The Router here is fine though since that is the default gateway equivalent to [the answer on how to change things from the command line](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/33098/5472).

Comment: What if you have multiple routes? Eg one straight to the internet and one via a VPN - How would you tell it to route all traffic over the VPN?

Comment: @Basic Set the VPN interface to be the default route. Then traffic to subnets that have other interfaces will still go elsewhere, but by default - everything else goes to the VPN. If you need _everything_ to be VPN, disable the other network interfaces.